# Can Activity B get the requestCode used in the startActivityForResult from Activity A

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, startactivityforresult

In Activity A, I start Activity B using

```
startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

Does Activity B have access to the requestCode used by Activity A to start Activity B?  I know I can separately include it as an Extra, but would like to simply access the requestCode directly in Activity B if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to send it in the bundle as an extra
And finish activity b with the request code

Answer (score 0):

On ActivityA:

You can do this:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    ActivityB activityB = new ActivityB;
    activityB.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

//
On Your Activity B:

```
//just call onActivityResult as you normally would.
```

Comment: I don't fully understand...won't onActivityResult in Activity B just receive responses from Activities started from Activity B (not ones started from Activity A)?

Comment: You are just passing the requestCode, resultCode and data obtained on your ActivityA's onActivityResult to ActivityB's onActivityResult(...) method.  You still need to call onActivityResult in your ActivityB to obtain those results.  Optionally, you can also use eventbus for this.

Comment: Doesn't Activity B need to finish before Activity A can receive that info in the onActivityResult method?